# question about transforming an equation when solving for solution in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a question regarding solving the ODE here:
[image]

My question is regarding the equation in the circle. So my teacher was saying the solution is of the form $y(x) = A sin(\mu x) + B cos(\mu x)$. And when we try to identify the A and B, she said B cannot be zero because it is in the denominator in the "circled" equation, so the value will "blow up". My question is can we not multiply both sides by B to get rid of B? and then we will have an equation like this:

$(A^2 + B) (sin (\mu L)) = 0$ and if we then set $B = - A^2$, does it mean that now we will have an entirely different solution? (based on the "conclusion" that B and A cannot be zero, so we have that the eigenvalue is $\mu = \frac{n\pi}{L}$ in order for that "circled" equation to be zero on both side, and then this give us the solution
of $y_n(x) = A_n sin (\frac{n\pi}{L}x) + B_n cos(\frac{n\pi}{L}x$).

So my question is am I allowed to do what I want to do "get rid of B in the denominator" that way? and set $B = -A^2$? and arrive at solution of $y(x) = A (sin\mu x) + B(cos\mu x)$ for pretty much any A and B? (since A can be arbitrary, as long as we have a B such that $B = -A^2$)?

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher's reason for $B\neq0$ is a bad one. They multiply both equations by $A/B$, at which point they are assuming that $B\neq0.$ Basically, $B$ is in the denominator because they put it there. If in fact $B=0$, then we find (assuming $A\neq0)$

$$\sin(\mu L)=0,$$
$$\cos(\mu L)=1,$$

and in this case we must have $\mu=2\pi n/L$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (as you should check), and the solution is then given by a Fourier sine series. All is fine, but $\mu$ is different, and the coefficients $A_n$ will be different.

If you multiply the equation by $B$ as you suggest, then you actually have $(A^2+B^2)\sin(\mu L)=0,$ not $(A^2+B)\sin(\mu L)=0,$ so you cannot set $B=-A^2$ as you suggest. $A^2+B^2$ is never zero unless $A=B=0.$

Comment: @innerproducet  Hello, so actually B = 0 also makes a valid solution in this case right? Since if I set B = 0 in the two equation: $B = A (sin \mu L) + B cos (\mu L)$, and $A \mu = A\mu (cos \mu L) - B \mu (sin \mu L)$, then like what you said (also I have checked) that $\mu = \frac{2\pi n}{L } n \in N$ will work.

Comment: @innerproducet  And so the solution can be of the form $y(x) = A sin(\mu x)$ for $\mu = \frac{2\pi n}{L } n \in N$

Comment: Yes, but this is not the most general solution because you are assuming from the outset that $B=0$ and so the solution has the form $y(x)=A\sin(\mu L)$. If you want the most general solution you have to take $A,B$ nonzero. But $y(x)=A\sin(\mu L)$ with $\mu=2\pi n/L$ is a solution that satisfies the boundary conditions, as you can check by plugging it into the ODE and by checking the BC directly.

Comment: So does it mean I should do some manipulation of the two equations (i.e. the y(x) and $y^\prime (x)$) and try to show that B not being zero will also given another set of solutions?  But it is just that the way my teacher is doing to show B must be non-zero in order to have non-trivial solution involving $cos(n\pi x)$ series is not really correct.  So I should try to arrive at the same solution (the general solution) as the one given here by my teacher? but I should not claim B cannot be zero the way my teacher is doing, is it right? I should try to show B not zero using other ways, right?